# Not being able to edit user's info in linux

Tags: linux, shell-script, usermod

I have managed to write this code. It runs, but no change was made to the user's info. It seems like `usermod` isn't working. What I am wanting to do is, to be able to edit existing user's info in the system?

```
printf "\nEnter user name to edit: "
read -r usermod
[ -n $usermod ] && usermod $usermod
unset usermod
echo " A user name has been edited"
```

Comment: Doesn't `usermod` on Linux require options that specify what kind of modifications you'd want to do? That code should give you an error message (but you don't say what goes wrong or what you actually want to do).

Comment: the wrong with this code it doesn't edit the users in the system. I am trying to write a shell script program that allows editing existing users in the system and it must edit the existing users in the system.

Comment: In _what way_ do you want to edit the user? If you want to add a secondary group, you would have to use `usermod` with `-a G groupname`, if you want to change their shell, you would have to use `usermod` with `-s shellpath`, etc. Is it `chfn` rather than`usermod` you want to use, maybe? `chfn` will allow you to interactively edit user information if you only use it with a username as `chfn username`.

Comment: I just want to edit users which I have added in the system. could you help me with a starting point, I am a bit unsure how to start?

Comment: What about the user data do you want to change?

Comment: I want to edit the username and password.

Comment: Have you read `man usermod` to see if and how you could do that using this command? It seems to me that although you can change the username you can't change the password using this tool

Comment: I have read about the usermod and this only allows to edit existing users but how do you write on the shell script that edits users, I have a bit unsure that I have tried this but can't make it work. 
printf "\nEnter user name to edit: "
            read -r usermod
            [ -n $usermod ] && usermod $usermod
            unset usermod
 echo " A user name has been edited" @roaima

Comment: I can read your question so there's no need to repeat it in a comment. You haven't explained what you want to edit other than "_username and password_". I've asked if you've read the documentation. If you haven't, then go and do so, as otherwise you're shooting in the dark.

Comment: I want to edit users "username and password" and also edit the groups. That's all I am trying to do, need a bit of help with starting point @roaima

Comment: @MukundaPaudel The starting point, as roaima said, is to read the `usermod` manual (see `man usermod` in a terminal).  There you will notice that you will have to supply specific options to use `usermod` to edit specific things, which means that you can't just say `usermod $usermod`.

Comment: thank you @kusalananda